# Performance degrades when deleting many records in database (SqlServer / EF5)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have database cleaning job that uses Entity Framework 5. There are quite some business rules to determine if an Entity should be deleted from the database or not, also if one parent Entity should be deleted various related Entities should also be deleted. The job first creates a DbContext on which all other queries and .Remove(someObj) operations are performed against. Every time a parent and all its related entities are have been marked for deletion using .Remove() I call .SaveChanges(). I have set db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

I notice performance slows considerably over time.

For example, in a database with 5000 entities where 500 should be deleted, the execution time is approx 1:30. Whereas should I modify the rules so that 1000 are to be deleted the execution time goes up to 7 minutes!

I tried to pay attention not to load more data than necessary into the context and minimize the number of queries that gets executed to the database. Still, the first 100 is much, much faster to remove than the last 100 in the same job.

Why? Total memory usage and the number of performed queries to the database seems reasonable.

Spliting the work into smaller chunks of for example 100, and create a new DbContext for each chunk, seem not to help.

Is there any other thing I might consider? Could it be database or index related?

The Code (it should create a new DbContext for every 10 parent iteration and call .SaveChanges() on every parent):

```
    public void DeleteIndividuals(siteId)
    {     
        deleteShippedIndividuals(siteId, 30);
    }


    private void deleteShippedIndividuals(Guid siteId, int numberOfDaysUntilDelete)
    {
        double? numberOfDaysUntilDelete_double = Convert.ToDouble(numberOfDaysUntilDelete);

        bool cont = true;

        do
        {
            db = new TrackAndTraceEntities();
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            //Get Top level parents with status SHIPPED 
            var topLevelIndividuals = (from i in db.Individuals
                                       where i.IndividualStatusType.Id == TrackAndTraceConstants.IndividualStatusId.SHIPPED
                                       && i.Parent == null
                                       && i.SiteId == siteId
                                       && DateTime.Now > SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", numberOfDaysUntilDelete_double, i.LastUpdate)
                                       orderby i.LastUpdate
                                       select i).Take(10).ToList();
            if (topLevelIndividuals.Count > 0)
            {
                cont = true;
            }
            else
            {
                cont = false;
            }

            //For each top level parent where has expire date is passed
            foreach (Individual topLevelIndividual in topLevelIndividuals)
            {
                deleteShippedIndividual(topLevelIndividual, numberOfDaysUntilDelete);
            }

        } while (cont);

    }

    private void deleteShippedIndividual(Individual topLevelIndividual, int numberOfDaysUntilDelete)
    {
        //Get all children on all levels in one big list
        List<Individual> allChildren = new List<Individual>();
        getAllChildren(topLevelIndividual, allChildren);

        //Iterate all children and check if all are not in status SHIPPED or have not expired
        foreach (Individual child in allChildren)
        {
            if (child.IndividualStatusType.Id != TrackAndTraceConstants.IndividualStatusId.SHIPPED)
            {
                //If structure has any child where status != SHIPPED, don't delete.
                return;
            }
            if (!(DateTime.Now > child.LastUpdate.AddDays(numberOfDaysUntilDelete)))
            {
                //If structure has any child that has not yet expired, don't delete.
                return;
            }
        }

        //Else delete entrie structure
        deleteEntireStructure(topLevelIndividual); 
    }

    private void getAllChildren(Individual parent, List<Individual> target)
    {
        var children = db.Individuals.Include("IndividualStatusType").Include("IndividualTests").Include("IndividualAdditionalNumbers").Where(i => i.Parent.Id == parent.Id).ToList();

        foreach (Individual child in children)
        {
            target.Add(child);
            getAllChildren(child, target);
        }

    }

    private void deleteEntireStructure(Individual topLevelIndividual)
    {
        try
        {
            //Structure must be deleted bottom up, so start with all leaf children
            if (topLevelIndividual.ChildIndividuals != null && topLevelIndividual.ChildIndividuals.Count > 0)
            {
                deleteLeafChildren(topLevelIndividual.ChildIndividuals.ToList());
            }

            //Finally delete the top parent
            doDeleteIndividual(topLevelIndividual);

            //And save changes
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log and continue
            string shortMessage = "Failed to delete individual structure (top parent serialnumber = " + topLevelIndividual.SerialNo + ", site = " + topLevelIndividual.SiteId.ToString();
            string details = getExceptionDetails(ex);
            this.textBox1.Text += DateTime.Now + ": " + shortMessage + Environment.NewLine + details + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }

    private void deleteLeafChildren(List<Individual> children)
    {
        foreach (Individual child in children)
        {
            if (child.ChildIndividuals != null && child.ChildIndividuals.Count > 0)
            {
                deleteLeafChildren(child.ChildIndividuals.ToList());
            }

            doDeleteIndividual(child);

        }
    }

    private void doDeleteIndividual(Individual individual)
    {
        //Delete all additional numbers
        foreach (IndividualAdditionalNumber i in individual.IndividualAdditionalNumbers.ToList())
        {
            db.IndividualAdditionalNumbers.Remove(i);
        }
        individual.IndividualAdditionalNumbers = new List<IndividualAdditionalNumber>();

        // Delete tests
        foreach (IndividualTest i in individual.IndividualTests.ToList())
        {
            db.IndividualTests.Remove(i);
        }
        individual.IndividualTests = new List<IndividualTest>();

        db.Individuals.Remove(individual);
    }
```

Comment: One wired thing I notice is that if modify my job to only process the first 100 records, and then launch it for example 10 times to delete 1000 records, then this will be much faster than to loop 10 times inside the job and createing a new DbContext in each iteration (also tried to sleep for some seconds in the iteration). 

Could it be something in ADO.NET? Job priority? Connection pool?

Comment: In the Entity Model you can set cascading deletes on relationships. Has this been set? If you do that, all you do is delete the parent object deleted and SaveChanges() will cascade the deletion to all children, and to all their children etc. You have to set the cascade on all relationships you want automatically deleted.

Comment: Ok, may try that, but it still seems wired that the first 100 so much faster than the last 100. I've also tried to disable indexes before doing running the job - no change, tried to call .SaveChanges() only each 30 deleted parents - no change. BTW we have snapshot on: ALTER DATABASE MyDb SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON
ALTER DATABASE MyDb SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that could happen is that the context holds too much information about the entities that are modified that it takes more and more to execute.

Make sure you are initializing on each iteration the context and that the old context goes beyond scope so that the GC can collect it.

What I would suggest though, would be that you bypass the "normal" way to remove entities and use something like this

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM "+table+" WHERE something="+value);
```

Though you must have made all the appropriate checks and be sure that the queries are executed in the right order.

The approach above also makes sure that you execute one query all around and not one query for each row.

Try something like this (I had a similar problem and this solution worked well enough)

```
 class deleter
 {
     DbContext context = new DbContext();

     private void ExecuteInIterations(){
          List<int> idsToDelete = context.ItemsToDelete.Where(......).Select(x=>x.Id).ToList();
          for(/*Number of items*/)
          {
               context = new DbContext();
               ExecuteOneIteration(idsToDelete,startIndex,endIndex);
          }
     }

     private void ExecuteOneIteration(List<int> idsToDelete, int start, int end){
           // Do whatever in here
     }
 }
```

After seeing your code I would suggest the following change

```
private void deleteShippedIndividuals(Guid siteId, int numberOfDaysUntilDelete)
{
    double? numberOfDaysUntilDelete_double = Convert.ToDouble(numberOfDaysUntilDelete);

    bool cont = true;

    do
    {
        using(var db = new TrackAndTraceEntities())
        {
            db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            //Get Top level parents with status SHIPPED 
            var topLevelIndividuals = (from i in db.Individuals
                                   where i.IndividualStatusType.Id == TrackAndTraceConstants.IndividualStatusId.SHIPPED
                                   && i.Parent == null
                                   && i.SiteId == siteId
                                   && DateTime.Now > SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", numberOfDaysUntilDelete_double, i.LastUpdate)
                                   orderby i.LastUpdate
                                   select i).Take(10).ToList();

            if (topLevelIndividuals.Count > 0)
                cont = true;
            else 
                cont = false;

            //For each top level parent where has expire date is passed
            foreach (Individual topLevelIndividual in topLevelIndividuals)
            {
                deleteShippedIndividual(topLevelIndividual, numberOfDaysUntilDelete);
            }

        } while (cont);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, I find using EF for determining if an Entity should be deleted, and context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DELETE FROM "+table+" WHERE something="+id); for the actual delete to be faster (although some performance degradation also here). It's strange though that even if I create a new DbContext for each parent iteration performance becomes really, really poor after running only 50 or so iterations. The DbContext must be more or less empty and we're not talking about a huge database, only a couple of thousand records.

Comment: Yes but are you totally discarding the previous context?

Comment: Yes. For each "parent" iteration, 1. Create new DbContext, 2. Delete all related entities using .Remove(), 3. Call .SaveChanges(). At first parents are deleted at a rate of 10 per second, in the end its 1 per second. The wired thing: if I restart the job I'm immediately back to 10 per second again, but putting in a Sleep() in the loop does not help.

Comment: This is very weird indeed, and without the code I cannot think of anything more. There was though a similar bug in EF5 code first (though I cannot put my finger on it). Maybe switching to another version of EF will resolve the problem. Good luck.

Comment: Using provides proper handling of the IDisposable context. It is a proper practice and it might solve your problem if this is a Garbage Collection problem. I do not know where and how you initialize the db variable (I guess it is a member of your class). If the context db is static it might be that the GC keeps in memory all of the deleted and cached entities and that is why the program is fast once  again when you restart the application.

Comment: No it's not static. 
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    TrackAndTraceEntities db = null;
    //...
}